# Is there any scaffold templates for BreezeJS?

Tags: breeze, scaffold

Examples are great, but scaffolding some templates for your existing odata model entities would be a way better start and would reduce waste time for repetitive work a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd like to contribute such templates? We would welcome them ... or at least an example as we're not clear on what template would be most valuable for this purpose. I know this sounds snarky but it's a genuine request for help.